# use .tfignore to hide non workspace folders

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops

I have VS2015 connected to account on visualstudio.com to host our source control repositories. We are using both flavours offered; TFVC and GIT. When we are connected to our TFVC repository the files added in the GIT repo's are appearing in the promote changes window, thousands of them!

Our workspace/repo's are mapped similar to the below

TFS Workspace - D:\TFS-Solution

```
D:\TFS-Solution\Project-A
D:\TFS-Solution\Project-B
D:\TFS-Solution\Project-C
```

GIT Repos - D:\GIT-Repo

```
D:\GIT-Repo\Project-A
D:\GIT-Repo\Project-B
D:\GIT-Repo\Project-C
```

When I open a project mapped to the TFS workspace and look at the pending changes there are thousands of files reported in the Detected link. When I click this to display the 'Promote Candidate Changes' dialog all the files listed are located in D:\GIT-Repo. Outside of the scope of this workspace/mapped folder.

I have tried to add the following paths to our .tfignore file but to no avail:

```
D:\GIT-Repo\*
..\..\GIT-Repo\*
```

How can I hide the GIT source controlled files from our TFVC workspace??

Comment: Do you have projects that have both TFVC and GIT repos at the same time? Which update of VS2015 are you using? The earlier version had problems with this scenario, but they made improvements. Maybe try with VS2015 Update 2 RC

Comment: There is no overlap both the TFVC and GIT projects are completely independent of each other. Hence I'd like to enforce the ignore. Im using VS2015 Update 1. I'll look into the Update 2 RC. Cheers

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your work space mappings?

Comment: I only have a single TFS workspace mapping - https://goo.gl/photos/EAnwsFeFwTkfGmCh7

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are mapping the team project collection (DefaultCollection) to D:\, so the files can be detected.

Remove the mapping for the team project collection, and map each team projects, you won't see the detected items.

Comment: Our workspaces are NOT mapped to the root of the D: drive. If I look in visual studios source control explorer window the DefaultCollection is not mapped. We are mapped as follows - name.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection\ProjectName > D:\ProjectName

Comment: Can't reproduce your scenario. Did you try to remove the map and create another two workspaces to test?